# Can you run JSNode scripting on standard hosting packages?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am relatively new to the server-side scripted JSnode environment and I found mixed answers when I was looking online for what is needed to run JSnode on my server. I am primarily looking to replace my PHP with JSnode and I was wondering if I would be able to do that without my host having to install any new server packages. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run server side JavaScript that depends on Node.js without the host having installed Node.js.

Node.js itself doesn't have any unusual dependancies. It does require installing on the server though (and it is not a common option for hosting services, I've only used it when I've had root access to a VPS). If you want to interact with it from Apache (for example) you might need to install something along the lines of mod_proxy.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it without installing the new server packages.